# Issue in XSD pattern for semicolon separated list of double values

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XSD pattern to realize a semicolon separated list of double values

```
<xs:pattern value="([-+]?(\d+)?(.\d+)?(([eE][-+]?)?\d+)?|(NaN))(;(([-+]?(\d+)?(.\d+)?(([eE][-+]?)?\d+)?)|(NaN)))*"/>
```

This works fine with the double values from this [data2type](https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xml-schema/datentypen-referenz/xs-double/) website:

```
<test>123.456;+123.456;-1.234e56;-.45E-6;NaN</test>
```

But why is the replacement of the dot with any other character valid to this pattern?

```
<test>123f456;+123.456;-1.234e56;-.45E-6;NaN</test>
```

How can I change the pattern so that the second example is invalid?

Also recommendations to improve the pattern are very welcome! :)

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to keep your schemas standard, but in case it's of any interest, the Saxon schema processor has an extension allowing you to declare this as a list type with `xs:double` as the item type and ";" (in place of whitespace) as the separator.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @MichaelKay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this useful: https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html
Also, I suspect that your problem is not related to XSD regex language, so any of the free online regex testers would help you to find this sort of thing.

In a regular expression, a dot represents exactly one occurrence of any character. If you want to specify a *literal* dot `.` (for the decimal point) then you need to escape it with a backslash `\.`.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that website. Also your `\.` fix worked well.